# Regex - Extract the first word from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I want to parse the text below:

> Recipient Name: Tracy Chan SKU: 103990

I want to extract "Tracy" only, the first word after "Recipient Name:" as the first name

So I got as far as `/(?<=Recipient Name: )(.*)(?= SKU)/gm` but it only gives me "Tracy Chan".... Using the ECMA option in Regex101...

Appreciate any help on this.

Thanks, Tracy

Comment: This would work as well  `str.split(' ')[2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract "Tracy" only, you can use the following regular expression:

```
/(?<=Recipient Name: )(\S+)/gm
```

This will match the first word (i.e., the first sequence of non-whitespace characters) after the "Recipient Name:" string.

The `\S` character class matches any non-whitespace character, and the `+` quantifier specifies that the preceding pattern should be matched one or more times until the first whitespace.

a working example:

```js
const input = "Recipient Name: Tracy Chan SKU: 103990";
const regex = /(?<=Recipient Name: )(\S+)/gm;
const matches = regex.exec(input);
console.log(matches[0]);  // "Tracy"
```

Update: based on your comments below, you also need to extract the last name from your string value.
I would suggest to either use the original regex written in your question, or use this one, in order to extract both `Tracy` and `Chan`, then you can use the javascript `split` method` to split the string into an array with all the extracted names.

consider the following example:

```js
const input = "Recipient Name: Tracy Chan SKU: 103990";
    const regex = /(?<=Recipient Name: )([^ ]+)\s([^ ]+)/gm;
    const allMatches = input.match(regex);
    let resultArray = allMatches[0].split(' ');
    console.log('firstName: '+ resultArray[0]);  // "Tracy"
    console.log('lastName: '+ resultArray[1]);  // "Chan"
```

Comment: This one works for me! Now I have to extract "Chan" the first word before "  SKU", does regex have a extract first word before string command? Thanks again!

Comment: you can then modify the regex to match the one in your question, and use the `split` method as per @dale suggestion then you would end up with an array of 2 elements: `['Tracy', 'Chan']`.

Comment: Sorry, I am extremely new Regex and i do not understand how to use the split method... do i use the look behind to get the value after the Recipient Name: and before SKU first and then split value into 2 arrays, then get the first word as first name and the last word before SKU as the last name?

Comment: No worries, we are all here to help and support each other. I will update my answer with an example that uses the `split` method. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `\S+` to match a sequence of non-whitespace characters, instead of `.*`, to get one word.

```js
let text = 'Recipient Name: Tracy Chan SKU: 103990';
let match = text.match(/(?<=Recipient Name: )\S+/);
console.log(match[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(?<=Recipient Name: )([^ ]+) .*(?= SKU)
```

This Works